# AddThis need to share custom url generated by js

Tags: javascript, share, addthis

I need the facebook/twitter/email buttons to share the page with the photo loaded. The script for the photo form was written years ago by a colleague that has left and I have concluded that it is something I am not able to customize myself. I have included as much info as I could think of. Thanks!

EDIT: I can provide wp login details for anyone that would like to take a stab at this for me. Very much appreciated!

1. Go to this page: etncal.staging.wpengine.com/community-event-photos/
2. Enter ID# 09070073, click Get Photo button
3. New page loads and the url will read: etncal.staging.wpengine.com/download-your-community-event-photos/?photo=090700731381779074495
4. A parameter has been passed to url and the photo code entered is the first 8 digits
5. Share this buttons are linking to the page url without parameter - so the blank page without the image loaded is being shared. Need to share page with unique url & photo.

Community Event Photo form uses two pages:

1] Page with form: 
etncal.staging.wpengine.com/community-event-photos/

Code added to body of this page:

```
[js]varUnique=new Date().getTime() //will always be unique
function CheckForm() {
var photoID = document.photoForm.photoID.value;
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
var eightdigit = /^\d{8}$/;
if(photoID.match(eightdigit)) {
var urlID = (photoID.concat(varUnique));
var newURL = 'http://etncal.staging.wpengine.com/download-your-community-event-photos/?photo=';
location.href=(newURL.concat(urlID));
return false;
} else {
alert('Please enter the eight digit number for your photo ID.');
return false;
}
}[/js]
```

2] Page that loads image:
etncal.staging.wpengine.com/download-your-community-event-photos/

Code added to body of this page:

```
<div class="clear-mg"></div>
<div class="photo">[js]
displayPhoto();
[/js]</div>
```

Link to the following js file is included in header of same wordpress page (click on 2nd button to right of Add Media, using a plugin to add):
etncal.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/canvas_child/js/photos.js

PHOTOS ARE LOCATED HERE:
etncal.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/canvas_child/images/community/photos/

Comment: Check other post of stackoverflow for a great answer
**Check**
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21891505/3329864

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the addthis:url parameter to a different value from the address bar. Here's the code on your page:

```
<div addthis:url='http://etncal.staging.wpengine.com/download-your-community-event-photos/' addthis:title='Download Your Community Event Photo ' class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
</div>
```

You need to set the addthis:url parameter to the URL of the photo page *or* set your  tag to the URL of the photo page.

Comment: Event attendees will go to the website and enter their 8 digit photo id and the 2nd page (which on load has the parameter added to the end) will display the photo. There are several hundred images in this directory, and so each url the addthis buttons share will be unique. I apologize for the confusion on my end, but does this make sense or am I still not understanding your instructions?

Comment: The addthis:url parameter needs to be set to the URL you want to share. If it's set to something different then you'll share that URL instead of the one you want to share.