# Social sharing widget without authentication, and with a custom js API, and integration to the backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, addthis

I would like to allow my users to share the the pages on my website, using a plug and play add-on such as 'AddThis'.

The problem with AddThis, is that I want to replace the value of the current page, with another page, that gets a  unique hash as a query parameter, to identify the person who shared the link, in case anyone clicks the link and enters the website.

To obtain the unique hash, I need to call a RESTful resource.

What I need is:

1. An ability to have a callback for the share click event, where I will trigger the AJAX request to get the unique hash from the server(creating a post entity, which holds a reference to the user_id, and the shared object).
2. After the AJAX request completes, I need to set the share link.

Of course I need to repeat 1 and 2 for each new post \ user, and I need them to happen before the share dialog actually opens(with the default \ previous link)

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368219/addthis-need-to-share-custom-url-generated-by-js) demonstrates a similar issue, but it hasn't been correctly answered either.